# Monkeyrunner on Ubuntu 16.04 to install android apk file

Tags: android, python, adb, apk, monkeyrunner

I have installed `Android SDK` on Ubuntu 16.04 which runs on Virtual Box on my laptop. I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab connected to the laptop. The device is accessible to the Virtual Machine. I try to install my android app (`apk file`)
using monkeyrunner.

The python script that I use is below

```
# Imports the monkeyrunner modules used by this program
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

# Connects to the current device, returning a MonkeyDevice object
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

# Installs the Android package. Notice that this method returns a boolean, so you can test
# to see if the installation worked.
device.installPackage('myproject/bin/MyApplication.apk')

# sets a variable with the package's internal name
package = 'com.example.android.myapplication'

# sets a variable with the name of an Activity in the package
activity = 'com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity'

# sets the name of the component to start
runComponent = package + '/' + activity

# Runs the component
device.startActivity(component=runComponent)

# Presses the Menu button
device.press('KEYCODE_MENU', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)

# Takes a screenshot
result = device.takeSnapshot()

# Writes the screenshot to a file
result.writeToFile('myproject/shot1.png','png')
```

I run the script as

```
monkeyrunner -v ALL ~/Workspace/monkey_runner_sample.py
```

I get the following output and nothing happens. The program sort of hangs.

```
170209 11:19:27.878:I [main] [com.android.chimpchat.ChimpManager] Monkey Command: wake.
170209 11:19:31.146:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] Error starting command: monkey --port 12345
170209 11:19:31.146:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException
170209 11:19:31.146:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]  at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:766)
170209 11:19:31.146:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]  at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.read(AdbHelper.java:735)
170209 11:19:31.146:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]  at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.readAdbResponse(AdbHelper.java:221)
170209 11:19:31.146:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]  at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:455)
170209 11:19:31.146:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]  at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:381)
170209 11:19:31.146:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]  at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:352)
170209 11:19:31.146:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]  at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:604)
170209 11:19:31.146:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]  at com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice$1.run(AdbChimpDevice.java:105)
170209 11:19:31.146:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
170209 11:19:31.146:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
170209 11:19:31.146:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
170209 11:19:31.146:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
170209 11:19:31.146:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The application `MyApplication` is not getting installed on the tablet.

The errors are given below

```
170209 11:27:07.692:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] Error starting command: monkey --port 12345
170209 11:27:07.692:S [pool-1-thread-1] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]com.android.ddmlib.TimeoutException
```

Could anyone help me figure out what is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) and with only a few changes on your original `monkeyrunner` script, you can get it running.

The base script was generated by [culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/culebra) which is always a good starting point.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Copyright (C) 2013-2016  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2017-02-08 by Culebra v12.5.3
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
'''


import re
import sys
import os


from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
from com.dtmilano.android.adb.adbclient import DOWN_AND_UP

kwargs1 = {'ignoreversioncheck': False, 'verbose': False, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(**kwargs1)
kwargs2 = {'forceviewserveruse': False, 'useuiautomatorhelper': False, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True, 'autodump': False, 'startviewserver': True, 'compresseddump': True}
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno, **kwargs2)

# Installs the Android package. Notice that this method returns a boolean, so you can test
# to see if the installation worked.
vc.installPackage('myproject/bin/MyApplication.apk')

# sets a variable with the package's internal name
package = 'com.example.android.myapplication'

# sets a variable with the name of an Activity in the package
activity = 'com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity'

# sets the name of the component to start
runComponent = package + '/' + activity

# Runs the component
device.startActivity(component=runComponent)

# Presses the Menu button
device.press('KEYCODE_MENU', DOWN_AND_UP)

# Writes the screenshot to a file (you can use a plain filename or use these placeholders)
vc.writeImageToFile('/tmp/${serialno}-${focusedwindowname}-${timestamp}.png', 'PNG')
```

Comment: Great. There are much more things that AndroidViewClient/culebra can do [compared to monkeyrunner](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2015/12/androidviewclientculebra-vs-monkeyrunner.html) , like supporting [multi device tests](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-culebra-multi-device.html), generating tests using GUI, [concertina](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2015/08/culebra-concertina-mode.html) and [decorating screenshots](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-obtaining-beautiful-screenshots.html) among others.

Comment: I am beginning to try that. Could you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149499/pressing-buttons-by-text-on-android-app-using-culebra when you get a chance.