# Pressing buttons by 'text' on Android app using Culebra

Tags: android, python, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I have a Android App that I am trying to test using `culebra`. The code is shown below.

```
'''reated on 2017-02-08 by Culebra v12.5.3
                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
'''


import re
import sys
import os


from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
from com.dtmilano.android.adb.adbclient import DOWN_AND_UP

kwargs1 = {'ignoreversioncheck': False, 'verbose': False, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(**kwargs1)
kwargs2 = {'forceviewserveruse': False, 'useuiautomatorhelper': False, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True, 'autodump': False, 'startviewserver': True, 'compresseddump': True}
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno, **kwargs2)

# Installs the Android package. Notice that this method returns a boolean, so you can test
# to see if the installation worked.
vc.installPackage('Abc App.Android.Abc App.Android-Signed.apk')


# sets a variable with the package's internal name
package = 'Abc App.Android.Abc App.Android'

# sets a variable with the name of an Activity in the packag
activity = 'md591ecfcc00ede54e89ae8714.MainActivity'

# sets the name of the component to start
runComponent = package + '/' + activity

# Runs the component
device.startActivity(component=runComponent)

vc.sleep(5)

#vc = ViewClient(device)
vc.dump()

for bt in [ 'PRO', 'FIE', 'DIA']:
    b = vc.findViewWithAttribute('text:mText', bt)
    if b:
        (x, y) = b.getXY()
        print >>sys.stderr, "clicking b%s @ (%d,%d) ..." % (bt, x, y)
        b.touch()

    time.sleep(7)


# Presses the Menu button
# device.press('KEYCODE_MENU', DOWN_AND_UP)

# Writes the screenshot to a file (you can use a plain filename or use these placeholders)
vc.writeImageToFile('/tmp/${serialno}-${focusedwindowname}-${timestamp}.png', 'PNG')
```

When I run the above script as

`$ python test_culebra.py`

I get the following error.

```
[100%] /data/local/tmp/AbcApp.Android.AbcApp.Android-Signed.apk
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/AbcApp.Android.AbcApp.Android-Signed.apk
Success
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "monkey_runner_culebra.py", line 53, in <module>
    print >>sys.stderr, "clicking b%s @ (%d,%d) ..." % (bt, x, y)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

It is installing and loading the app. However it is not able to find the button with the text `PRO',`FIE`,`DIA` etc.

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: It seems that `b.getXY()` is not returning the coordinates of the View. Check that `b` contains what you expect.

Comment: Also, use `culebra` or `culebra -G` to generate the touch for one case and then you can turn it into a loop. That way you'll have the correct syntax.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano - how do I use culbera -G inside the python script?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear enough. I'm not saying you can use `culebra -G` *inside* your script, but you can run it and then cut & paste the new generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
culebra -Gu -o myscript.py --scale=0.5
```

you'll see a window representing your device, much like

[image]

then you click on the buttons (I'm running ApiDemos here) and `culebra` generates

```
vc.dump(window=-1)
vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'NORMAL').touch()
vc.sleep(_s)
vc.dump(window=-1)
vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'SMALL').touch()
vc.sleep(_s)
vc.dump(window=-1)
vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'OFF').touch()
vc.sleep(_s)
vc.dump(window=-1)
```

which you can then manually turn into

```
for t in ['NORMAL', 'SMALL', 'OFF']:
    b = vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(t)
    print >> sys.stderr, "clicking", b,  "@", b.getXY()
    b.touch()
```

or even

```
for t in ['NORMAL', 'SMALL', 'OFF']:
    vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(t).touch()
```

this is assuming the screen does not change when you click your buttons, if it does you need to call `vc.dump()` again.

Then you can copy and paste to your original script.

Comment: I am not able to install Pillow on python 2.7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192775/installing-pillow-on-python-2-7