# Installing Pillow on Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

When I try to install Pillow (as a wheel file)

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install C:\Users\karth\Desktop\Pillow-3.4.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

I get the following error.

```
Pillow-3.4.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Comment: why do you install 36 ? instead of 27 ? your python script seems like 2.7

Comment: why not simply "pip install pillow" and be done with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wheel file which is expecting a different Python version.

The cp36, indicates CPython 3.6, i.e. Python 3.6. You are running Python 2.7.

Either update your Python version, or more suitably, get a wheel file of the correct version from PyPi https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/4.0.0